# Django OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to read values from an sqlite db I added to my Django project but it doesn't work.
I did a test in the Python shell and all it returned was the following error when I tried looking into the data:

```
from myapp.models import my_data
my_data.objects.all()
```

> OperationalError: no such column: my_table_name.id

This is how my models.py file looks like:

```
class my_data(models.Model):
    status = models.TextField(db_column='STATUS', blank=True, null=True)
    name_1 = models.TextField(db_column='NAME_1', blank=True, null=True) 
    name_2 = models.TextField(db_column='NAME_2', blank=True, null=True)  
    dep = models.IntegerField(db_column='DEP', blank=True, null=True) 
    name_reg = models.TextField(db_column='NAME_REG', blank=True, null=True)
    reg = models.IntegerField(db_column='REG', blank=True, null=True)
    name_com = models.TextField(db_column='NAME_COM', blank=True, null=True)
    avgp = models.IntegerField(db_column='AVGP', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'my_table_name'
```

My settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'my_table_name': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_my_table_name.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Also, I performed the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try add a id field which is AutoField like: id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

Comment: Why you add `my_table_name` key with `ENGINE` and `NAME` ?

Comment: @ Mahmut Can Tuncet: thanks it worked!

Comment: I see that you have two databases. Do you also have `DATABASE_ROUTERS` defined in `settings.py`? If not, then your database named `my_table_name` is never used. Note that `db_table = 'my_table_name'` defines the **table name** not the database name.

Comment: Also, how was the database table created? Did it exist before you started writing Django code? Or was it created by Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I write this according to this comment since you said it worked:*

Add a id field to `my_data` model:

```
AutoField like: id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Tip: In django model names should follow CamelCase convention.

Comment: `AutoField like: ...` is not valid python.

Comment: Also, Django should generate an `id` field automatically. I wonder why it doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before then i used the below code for my models.py file, this has resolved the issue

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This could help you to resolve the above Problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your models.py:

```py
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```